# Does an object have potential energy if Earth isn't in the system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, potential-energy

I know that the earth being in the system has some effect on the energy, but I honestly don't know what the effect is. Does earth being excluded from the system mean there is no PE? In that case, is energy still conserved?

Comment: Many types of potential energy exist, the type we often are referring to here on earth is the gravitational potential energy associated with an object raised to a certain height above the surface of the earth. If the earth is not in the system then the object cannot have gravitational potential energy wrt. the earth. It can still have other sorts of potential energy though or gravitational potential energy compared to some other massive object.

Comment: @Vinzent This is not a comment. Please consider converting it to an answer

Answer (score 1):

Without the earth, an object with mass would have gravitational potential energy relative to any other mass, such as the sun, other planets, or the center of the galaxy. A object with electric charge could have potential energy relative to any other charged object.  A nuclear particle has potential energy relative other nuclear particles.

Answer (score 0):

The term "potential" in potential energy is a somewhat abstract concept given to a body meaning that the body will willingly convert this potential energy into kinetic energy, ultimately resulting in a decrease in potential energy and a more "stable" state.

When it comes to gravity on earth, this potential energy is a specific type of potential energy, referring to the potential for an object to move closer to the earth and be in a more stable state with regards to its position from the earth.

If neither the earth nor any other masses were present in a given single-body system, that body would not have any gravitational potential energy, because it would not have any gravitational attraction towards another body, but other types of potential energy could be present, such as electrical, magnetic etc.

Mechanical energy is always conserved in a closed-system with no external forces. This means that potential energy and kinetic energy are simply "trading" with each other.

Hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that by "potential energy" you  mean gravitational potential energy since, as has been pointed out, there are other forms of potential energy.

An object does not, by itself, possess gravitational potential energy.

The concept of gravitational potential (as well as any other form of potential energy) is linked to a system- not to a single object. If the source of the  potential energy is the gravitational field of the Earth, then the gravitational potential energy is possessed by the object-earth system, not by the object alone.

Even in the absence of the Earth, an object would still be in the gravitational field of other planets and stars, most notably our own Sun. In the absence of the earth, that gravitational potential energy would be possessed by the object-Sun system. (FYI the acceleration due to the Sun's gravitational field at the distance between the Sun and the Earth is only about 0.0006 g, (g=9.81 m/s$^2$). So the Sun's contribution to the gravitational potential energy of the object would be negligible compared to the Earth) .

Hope this helps.